# MiniProfiler and Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mvc-mini-profiler

I have two separated projects "MyWeb" and "MyAPI", MyWEB is a one-page site with one controller and one view, it is based on the knockout MVVM and ajax requests to the MyAPI web application, this two projects are contains in different apppools. I had integrated the MiniProfiler with MyWEB site and it is worked good, but I can see only first load results of Home page and then all data is loading from MyAPI web app. So, I need to integrate MiniProfiler with MyAPI project that I had the ability to see miniprofiler results on page of MyWEB site. I know that MiniProfiler send ajax requests for getting results, but I'm not  understand why this requests are working only with the same domain. For example MyWEB is in domaint http://mywebsite.com and I send requests to MyAPI in domain http://mywebapi.com/api, also this two projects can be placed on two different computers. So, what I have in this time

MyWEB global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {

        }
    }
```

MyAPI global.asax

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.IsLocal)
            {
                MiniProfiler.Start();
            }
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            MiniProfiler.Stop();
        }
    }
```

MyAPI web.config handlers

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="MiniProfiler"/>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
```